# C# out of memory with file

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting a OutOfMemory exception when running the following code, it happens on the File.ReadLines line, it processes most files fine until it hits larger files.

It's consistantly using tons of memory and cpu during the whole process though.

The file it crashed on is only 156,000KB, which is 156mb

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.CursorVisible = false;

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("  [" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "]" + " Connected to the Cassandra Database");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

    string filepath = @"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\wecrack lists";
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);

    int fileCount = 0;

    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    var database = client.GetDatabase("cracking");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<Password>("passwords");

    foreach (var file in directory.GetFiles("*"))
    {
        fileCount++;

        Console.WriteLine("  [" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "]" + " Working through file: {" + file + "} {" + fileCount + "/" + directory.GetFiles("*").Count() + "}");

        List<Password> entitys = new List<Password>();

        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filepath + @"\" + file.ToString()))
        {
            entitys.Add(new Password { password = line });
        }

        collection.InsertManyAsync(entitys);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("  [" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "]" + " Finished inserting records, press any key to get the count.");
    Console.ReadKey(true);

    while (true)
    {
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running in 32 bit system or 64 bit? compiling with 64bit will help.. but you shouldn't keep everything in memory because that will never work as RAM is always limited.. try using weakreference in c#

Comment: I am not familiar with that InsertManyAsync. It that collection manage to keep the objects from entitys in memory then it is clear that you 'correctly' reach the end of your memory

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Try batching your updates. That way you won't have all that data in memory at the same time. It may also help you not totally lock up your database.

```
...

foreach (var file in directory.GetFiles("*"))
{
    fileCount++;

    Console.WriteLine("  [" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "]" + " Working through file: {" + file + "} {" + fileCount + "/" + directory.GetFiles("*").Count() + "}");

    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filepath + @"\" + file.ToString());

    while(!file.EndOfStream)
    {
        int passwordBatchCount = 0;
        List<Password> entitysBatch = new List<Password>();

        while ((string line = file.ReadLine()) != null && passwordBatchCount < BATCH_SIZE)
        {
            entitysBatch.Add(new Password { password = line });
            passwordBatchCount++;
        }

        collection.InsertManyAsync(entitysBatch);
    }

    file.Close();

    }
}

...
```